# How do I get the div below my navigation stay when hovered over?

Tags: jquery, html, mouseover

At resting state, the navigation menu looks like this. 
[image]

When I hover over it, it pushes the white space down.[image]

Naturally, I don't want this to happen, but I don't know how to go about making it stay where it is. My JQuery looks like this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $('li').mouseover( function() {
           $(this).animate({height: "40px"}, 300 );
        });
        $('li').mouseout( function() {
           $(this).animate({height: "18px"}, 300 );
        });

});
```

And my navigation is your typical ul with `display: inline-block;`
What I want is for it to just kind of hover over the white space, ignoring it? How could I do this?

Also, while I'm asking about the navigation, is there a way to make it just stay on hover and not bounce a couple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the animation is causing the div to enlarge. i would suggest making the div the eventual size to begin with with a white (or body BG color) bar at the bottom that the animation can naturally grow into.

Answer (score 1):

You need to play around with the `CSS` positioning of the navigation. If you make it `position: absolute` it wont affect other elements on the page that are outside of it's `div`.

It might screw up the original positioning a little, but will be easy to fix back to how you want it.

Not too sure what you mean by `and not bounce a couple times?`

Comment: When I hover over it, it kind of .. bounces instead of the height going to where it should, it goes up down up down and thens stays

Comment: That *might* be due to animations stacking up. You could try adding a `.stop()` function just before the `.animate()` like so: `$(this).stop().animate({height: "18px"}, 300 );`